# Re-imposition of slavery and racist laws in France under Napoleon

Tags: political-history, france, slavery, racism, napoleon

The last chapter of the Tom Reiss's [biography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17613045-the-black-count) of [General Alex Dumas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas-Alexandre_Dumas) tells in some detail the dark story of the re-imposition of slavery and very harsh race-based oppression by Napoleon, abrogating some of the finest achievements of the French Revolution:

> On May 20, 1802, the day after creating the Legion of Honor, Napoleon
> issued [another proclamation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_20_May_1802), one that revealed his true position on
> slavery in the French Empire. Colonies where the 1794 abolition hadn't
> gone into effect [...] were to officially remain in a state of
> pre-1789 slavery. [...] The door to the complete reimposition of
> slavery had been opened. This infamous clause was followed by a series
> of now forgotten laws that crushed the rights the Revolution had given
> to men of color within France.
>
> Two weeks after the slavery decree, Napoleon issued a law banning all
> officers and soldiers of color who had retired or been discharged from
> the army from living in Paris and the surrounding area. In July, a new
> order revived the [old royal Police des Noirs laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Noir), except now they
> forbade "blacks, mulattos, and men of color... from entering the
> continental territory of the Republic under any cause or pretext,
> unless supplied with special authorization." And this time the racist
> laws would be enforced, not merely proclaimed. All those in
> noncompliance would be held until deported. (p. 314)

Now, I looked a bit into the background: Napoleon [tried to seize Saint-Domingue/Haiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Domingue_expedition), acting in concert with Britain, Spain, and the US. (See [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4491574) by [Robin Blackburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Blackburn) for details). This "explains" the re-imposition of slavery by "reasons of state". But the question remains - why did Napoleon introduce the other extremely harsh racist laws mentioned above?

More precisely, my questions are:

1. Was Napoleon personally racist? In particular, compared to an average minor French noble of his generation?
2. Was any motivation or explanation officially given for these racist laws?
3. Are there records of some internal opposition to the racist laws within Napoleon's regime?

I am posing question #3 because recently I've read the magisterial study *[Napoleon and His Collaborators: The Making of a Dictatorship](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12801.Napoleon_and_His_Collaborators)* by Isser Woloch. There was some internal pushback on other issues from within the regime, in particular from major liberal figures like [Théophile Berlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9ophile_Berlier), Napoleon's "house Jacobin" and a member of the Council of State. But "race", "slavery", or "blacks" do not appear in the index to Woloch's fine book and I don't recall any mention of them.

Comment: An important point of context is that Napoleon's in-laws, the Beauharnais', were sugar-cane plantations owners who had built their fortune on sugar trade and slavery, and having suffered financially from the 1794 abolition, they lobbied energetically (among others) for re-imposition of slavery.

Comment: @Evargalo I didn't know that, quite a bit of context, indeed.

Comment: Haiti may be quite significant in this.  Hardcore History's Dan Carlin has a long podcast about [slavery](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/dan-carlins/show-68-blitz-human-resources-kGH4UQoFLl8/).  He bases a lot of it on Haiti and ends the podcast's timeline with the slave revolt there.  IIRC what he said was that Haiti provided a huge proportion of France's income via sugar (and maybe another commodity too?  indigo?).  Carlin examines in depth the contradictions between the French and American declarations of human rights, and their continued use of slavery.  Your Q may be answered in it.

Comment: IIRC Carlin also spoke of a dynamic in Haiti where full-Caucasian locals were aggrieved at the growing economic clout of freedmen and mixed race people, some of whom owned plantations IIRC.  This is similar to periods of European history when rich traders and merchants were pushed back by traditional nobility.   The point is that clawing back any concessions made to freedmen and mixed race people would have been part of that reaction.  An excellent podcast btw, if long at 5hrs.  Manages to barely use the term "racism" and to avoid the Civil War and later eras, while firmly condemning slavery